# Unexected results in Receive-Job

Tags: powershell, jobs, psobject

I noticed weird behavior when using jobs in PowerShell 5.0.
Running job that returns `PSObject`, also returns some hashtable.
Jobs that return strings, integers, etc work propertly.

Running

```
Start-Job { New-Object PSObject -Property @{ A = 1 } } |
  Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

returns

```
A                     : 1
RunspaceId            : 6921e85f-301e-4e95-8e4b-c0882fc2085f
PSSourceJobInstanceId : 2992ef77-5642-4eac-8617-f26449a87801
```

Running

```
Start-Job { New-Object PSObject } | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

returns

```
@{PSComputerName=localhost; RunspaceId=3e783d5f-254a-4951-bb4a-7ff6fa2812c5; PSShowComputerName=False; PSSourceJobInstanceId=1d951dec-0823-4cde-8219-4a6263550441}
```

However, running

```
Start-Job { ,@(New-Object PSObject -Property @{ A = 1 }) } |
  Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

returns

```
A
-
1
```

Why does `Receive-Job` cmdlet add that hashtable only for `PSObject`s?

**UPDATE**: Same in PowerShell 4.0.

Comment: FWIW, it behaves the same for PSCustomObject:
`Start-Job { [PSCustomObject]@{A=1} } | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob`

Comment: @PetSerAl, I didn't realize that it also adds note properties to integers and strings.

Could you write that as answer?

Comment: @PetSerAl: Great pointers, thank you. I don't think `.ToString()` is being called, however (at least not directly on the object), and there are 3 sets of 3-5 remoting-related properties that trigger this formatting (if they're the only properties). I've posted my findings as an answer - please let me know there if I got something wrong.

Comment: @PetSerAl: Got it, thanks again; the `.PSObject` part of `.PSObject.ToString()` was the missing puzzle piece - answer updated. (If there's something to add/correct, please comment _there_).

Answer (score 4):

PowerShell is not a WYSIWYG shell. Usually, "what you get" is not a text, but objects with properties and methods. And "what you see" is some text representation of them. In many cases by default PowerShell does not display all of the object's properties, but only most common ones, as defined in format files. And some objects use custom formatting, like strings and integers only display their value, but not any of its properties, and collections display their content but not collections themselves.

So, in fact, PowerShell adds extra properties to all objects received from job. But this properties not always get displayed. You can see that extra properties by passing job output to `Get-Member` cmdlet:

```
Start-Job { 1,'',@() } | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob | Get-Member
```

or to formatting cmdlet with appropriate options to force formatting primitive types and to not enumerate collection:

```
Start-Job { 1,'',@() } | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob | Format-List -Force -Expand CoreOnly
```

Answer (score 3):

To *complement* [PetSerAl's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40247579/45375) with a **focus on *the hashtable that wasn't*** (a hashtable), based on PetSerAl's helpful comments:

The output from `Start-Job { New-Object PSObject } | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob`,

```
@{PSComputerName=localhost; RunspaceId=3e783d5f-254a-4951-bb4a-7ff6fa2812c5; PSShowComputerName=False; PSSourceJobInstanceId=1d951dec-0823-4cde-8219-4a6263550441}
```

**only *looks* like a hashtable literal**; in fact, **it is the default output formatting for "property-less" *custom objects* that, in fact, *do* have properties, but *only ones added by PowerShell itself***.

<sup>This representation is suspiciously *similar* to a hashtable literal, but the quoting around values that would normally need it is missing - such as around `localhost`.

Also note that outputting an *actual* hashtable results in a much nicer, two-column key-value format.</sup>

Note that PS still considers a custom object that *originally* had no properties property-less even after PS itself has added properties to it, such as by `Receive-Job` here - see below for details.

**In its original state (no properties added by PS yet), a property-less object's default output is *empty*  (the empty string).** (Try `New-Object PSCustomObject` directly at the prompt.)

**Once `Receive-Job` has added its "meta" properties to the custom object, their existence triggers the hashtable-*like* output formatting.**

---

PetSerAl has provided a link to the [source code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/c3ce30e34a4546667ffc220ce47048ca70391971/src/System.Management.Automation/commands/utility/FormatAndOutput/common/FormatViewManager.cs#L486), which suggests that the **"PropertyLessObject" formatting is triggered under the following conditions**:

- An object has no properties at all or only has properties automatically added by PowerShell in the context of *remoting* (which apparently also includes *job*-related cmdlets), as done by `Receive-Object` here.
- To put it differently: Properties automatically added by PS aren't taken into account when deciding whether an object is propertyless.

The source-code link will tell you the specific 3-, 4-, or 5-element sets of remoting properties that may be added during remoting and trigger the formatting, but here's a minimal (3-property) example.
Again, note that the hashtable-like formatting is only triggered because the only properties that the object has are named for remoting-related, automatically added properties:

```
PS> [PSCustomObject] @{PSComputerName='Hi, Mom'; RunspaceId=0; PSShowComputerName=$true}
@{PSComputerName=Hi, Mom; RunspaceId=0; PSShowComputerName=False}
```

<sup>Note that even though a hashtable literal is *involved* in the command, it is merely used to *construct a custom object*.</sup>

You can **force a normal list or table view** with `Format-List -Force` or `Format-Table -Force`, but note that Boolean property `PSShowComputerName` *never* shows up and instead implicitly controls whether the *associated* `PSComputerName` property is included in the list / table.

---

PetSerAl also points out that you can **get the hashtable-*like* output format *on demand* for any *custom* object (`[pscustomobject]`):** simply invoke **`.PSObject.ToString()`** (note the crucial `.PSObject` part; without it, you get *empty* output).

```
PS> ([pscustomobject] @{ one = 'Hi, Mom'; two = 2 }).PSObject.ToString()
@{one=Hi, Mom; two=2}
```

Or, more simply, with **string interpolation** (which, presumably, simply calls `.PSObject.ToString()` behind the scenes):

```
PS> "$([pscustomobject] @{ one = 'Hi, Mom'; two = 2 })"
@{one=Hi, Mom; two=2}
```

Note that **this kind of string interpolation does *not* work for instances of any other types (objects *not* of type `[System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]`)**:

- PowerShell defers to their `.ToString()` method even when you invoke `.PSObject.ToString()`.
- A directly .NET-based type (e.g., as added with `Add-Type`) by default simply returns its *full type name* (both from `.ToString()` / `.PSObject.ToString()` and as default output in PS); e.g.:

  ```
  PS> (Add-Type -PassThru 'namespace net.same2u { public class SomeType {} }')::New()
  net.same2u.SomeType  # the full type name
  ```
- The same applies to instances of custom PowerShell classes (defined with `class { ... }`).