# Format [pscustomobject] instances returned by Invoke-RestMethod or ConvertFrom-Json

Tags: json, powershell, formatting, output-formatting

I am trying to create a table from a JSON file I am receiving from a RESTful API.

When I print the property of the json object I get an output like this:

```
PS> Write-Output JSON.Object

Object1           : @{key1=property; key2=property; key3=property; key4=property}
Object2           : @{key1=property; key2=property; key3=property; key4=property}
Object3           : @{key1=property; key2=property; key3=property; key4=property}
Object4           : @{key1=property; key2=property; key3=property; key4=property}
```

The output I would like to see is this:

```
Name              key1        key2        key3        key4
-----             ----        ----        ----        ----
Object1           property    property    property    property
Object2           property    property    property    property
Object3           property    property    property    property
```

In addition, is it possible to avoid displaying a specific key and it's properties?

Example:

```
Name              key1        key2        key4      # ← Not displaying key3
-----             ----        ----        ----
Object1           property    property    property
Object2           property    property    property
Object3           property    property    property
```

Comment: Try to pipe the output to `| Format-Table` and see if the output is okay for you.

Comment: Hello thank you for your response @MartinBrandl.

As you suggested,  I piped the JSON Object. Json.object | Format-Table
However, my out put still shows the key values in a hash table for example.

Object1 is residing over @{key1=property; key2=property}

I have been able to extract these properties using a nested for each, but beyond that I am not entire sure on how to place those values with the corresponding object.

Comment: Note: The output in the question _resembles_ hashtable literals, but that is _incidental_: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40253364/45375

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the parent keyname as a property `Name` to the nested objects:

```
$json.Object | ForEach-Object {
  foreach ($p in $_.PSObject.Properties) {
    $p.Value | Select-Object @{n='Name';e={$p.Name}},*
  }
}
```

Note that PowerShell will render the output in list form by default, since your objects have more than 4 properties. Pipe it through `Format-List -AutoSize` to get tabular output.

Comment: Hello, this is an excellence response. We are very close! However, is there a way to only have 'Name' once at the top of the Column instead of repeating for each new object?

Comment: @Badlarry I don't follow. Please update your question with the actual and the desired output.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have updated my question with the appropriate fields.

Comment: Like I already said in my answer, piping the loop output through `Format-Table` should give you what you want. Use the `-Exclude` parameter on `Select-Object` to remove particular properties.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers The code that Ansgar had wrote worked great, and I've been able to re-purpose and modify it with great understanding as well. Thanks for everything I've been able to write several more functions with the same logic.

Answer (score 2):

To *complement* [Ansgar Wiecher's elegant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41089438/45375) with **background information**:

Let's define sample input that simulates a single, nested object converted to a PowerShell `[pscustomobject]` instance via `ConvertFrom-Json`:

```
$objFromJson = [pscustomobject] @{ 
  Object1 = [pscustomobject] @{key1='o11'; key2='o12'; key3='o13'; key4='o14'}
  Object2 = [pscustomobject] @{key1='o21'; key2='o22'; key3='o23'; key4='o24'} 
  Object3 = [pscustomobject] @{key1='o31'; key2='o32'; key3='o33'; key4='o34'} 
  Object4 = [pscustomobject] @{key1='o41'; key2='o42'; key3='o43'; key4='o44'} 
  Object5 = [pscustomobject] @{key1='o51'; key2='o52'; key3='o53'; key4='o54'} 
}
```

Outputting `$objFromJson` gives output that is formatted as in the question.

#### Why does this result in the output formatting shown in the question?

For types such as `[pscustomobject]`, which do *not* have [explicit formatting definitions defined for them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml) (via `*.ps1xml` files and loaded implicitly into the session or explicitly via [`Update-FormatData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/update-formatdata)), PowerShell decides what default formatting to use based on the *number of properties* of the type:

- A type with up to 4 properties implicitly uses `Format-Table`
- a type with  5 or more properties implicitly uses `Format-List`

<sup>The sample input in the question is presumably *abridged*; with truly only 4 properties, a *tabular* display would have resulted.</sup>

The ***properties themselves* are rendered by calling `.PSObject.ToString()`** on their values, which is typically the same representation you'd get if you referenced the object inside a double-quoted string, except that the latter always uses culture-*invariant* formatting, whereas `.ToString()` will respect the current culture, if the type supports it.

In the case of a `[pscustomobject]` instance, this results in a representation that *resembles* a hashtable literal, but isn't one (for background information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40253364/45375)); e.g.:

```
PS> $objFromJson.Object1.PSObject.ToString()
@{key1=o11; key2=o12; key3=o13; key4=o14}
```

#### Reshaping the data as desired:

There is no way to use formatting cmdlets such as `Format-Table` *directly* to yield the desired output - the data must be *reshaped* first:

Specifically, the properties of object `$objFromJson` must be reshaped into a *collection of custom objects*:

- whose `Name` property contains the *name* of a given property, and
- whose other properties are the properties of the object of that property's *value*; in other words: the properties of the input property's *value* must be made properties of the output object itself.

Extracting `$objFromJson`'s properties is facilitated by PowerShell adding (among others) a hidden `.PSObject` property to all objects, whose own `.Properties` property contains a collection of all the object's property *definitions* (name, value, additional metadata such as the type of property, ...); e.g.:

```
PS> $objFromJson.Object1.PSObject.Properties
MemberType      : NoteProperty
IsSettable      : True
IsGettable      : True
Value           : o11
TypeNameOfValue : System.String
Name            : key1
IsInstance      : True
# ... remaining properties
```

Outputting the collection of `$objFromJson`'s *property definitions* and extracting only the definitions' `Name` and `Value` properties is a step in the right direction:

```
PS> $objFromJson.PSObject.Properties | Select-Object Name, Value

Name    Value                                    
----    -----                                    
Object1 @{key1=o11; key2=o12; key3=o13; key4=o14}
Object2 @{key1=o21; key2=o22; key3=o23; key4=o24}
Object3 @{key1=o31; key2=o32; key3=o33; key4=o34}
Object4 @{key1=o41; key2=o42; key3=o43; key4=o44}
Object5 @{key1=o51; key2=o52; key3=o53; key4=o54}
```

However, we must make the properties of the `.Value` property *direct properties* of the output objects to get output with property-individual values.

Ansgar's elegant answer demonstrates how to do that in a single pipeline.
Let me complement it with a *reusable helper function* derived from it:

```
function ConvertTo-Collection($InputObject) {
  foreach ($obj in $InputObject) {
    foreach ($prop in $obj.PSObject.Properties) {
      $prop.Value | Select-Object @{ n='Name'; e={ $prop.Name }}, *
    }
  } 
}
```

With that function in place, the desired output can now be achieved thus:

```
ConvertTo-Collection $objFromJson | Format-Table
```

To exclude a specific property, such as `key3`:

```
ConvertTo-Collection $objFromJson | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty key3 |
  Format-Table
```

Comment: Thats a nice answer.